# BIRT report designer can't see my java classes

Tags: java, javascript, designer, birt, rhino

We are developing a couple reports with BIRT, that will be run through the report engine API to produce .XLS or .PDF output according to user's choice. We are using BIRT RCP Designer 4.2.1 (standalone) because Eclipse plugins made GWT plugin to stop working (at all). All data access is made through javascript and scripted data sets.
In order to get a more accurate preview of the layout, I wanted to create some mock-up data transfer objects when the report is run whithin the BIRT Report Designer, but when run in the designer (preview tab), it throws exceptions which suggest that my classes aren't where the report expects them.
I've tried adding them to the "Window > Preferences > Report Design > Classpath" of BIRT Report Designer as external class folder (pointing at the target/myProyect/WEB-INF/classes directory) and as external jar. In both cases a get the same errors.
If I try to create my objects as

```
informeSeguimiento = new Packages.my.company.project.backend.model.business.InformeSeguimiento();
informeSeguimiento.setVolumen(35800000);
informeSeguimiento.setFechaInforme(new Packages.java.util.Date());
```

I get `TypeError: [JavaPackage my.company.project.backend.model.business.InformeSeguimiento] is not a function, it is object. (/report/method[@name="initialize"]#65) (Element ID:1)`

If I try to create it with

```
importPackage( Packages.my.company.project.backend.model.business );
informeSeguimiento = new InformeSeguimiento();
```

I get `ReferenceError: "InformeSeguimiento" is not defined. (/report/method[@name="initialize"]#64) (Element ID:1)`

And if I try to create it with

```
informeSeguimiento = new my.company.project.backend.model.business.InformeSeguimiento();
```

I get `TypeError: [JavaPackage my.company.project.backend.model.business.InformeSeguimiento] is not a function, it is object. (/report/method[@name="initialize"]#63) (Element ID:1)` again.

Any idea about what can I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Little late in answering, hope it helps someone else,I had same problem of preview report in Eclipse Java Web Application. I followed instructions as per this blog. It worked.

> Please have a look at [BIRT Designer Classpath Changes](http://birtworld.blogspot.de/2009/12/birt-designer-classpath-changes.html) blog page.

Check if BIRT RCP Designer has same settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new classpath variable to point to the folder containing your .class file in java buildpath. go to:

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables

Comment: There isn't any "Java" item in BIRT Designer's "Window -> Preferences"

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I didn't notice that you are using BIRT RCP Designer